# How to use SQL command "Update" in android

Tags: android

This may sound very simple and off the track, but any help will be highly appreciated. How can we execute raw UPDATE command of SQLite in Android just like we can execute rawQuery(..,  ). We have SQLiteDatabase.update(  ) but how to run a raw update like

```
UPDATE STATS SET TEMP_F = 74.9 
WHERE ID = 44 
AND MONTH = 7;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The perferred method is to use the [SQLiteDatabase convenience class "update"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

*update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)*

examples:

> db.update("my_table", cvValues, "id=25", null);
>
> -- OR --
>
> db.execSQL(strSQL); // open update; not to be used with SELECT

Comment: Thas db.execSQL(strSQL) was what I was looking for. Thanks